# box2d crush on SetActive

Tags: cocos2d-x, box2d

I'm writing a game on `cocos2d-x` with `box2d physics`, I'm disabling some fixtures when they go off the screen.

But I got this error:

```
Assertion failed: (m_world->IsLocked() == false), function SetActive
```

while I'm doing this:

```
_physicsBody->SetActive(false);
```

anyone knows what's happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all who replied, you have helped me..
so everybody with this problem you have to just mark your nodes as dirty or something and then on update you can do whatever you would like to do with your bodies.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

While the world is being updated, you are limited in what you can change. So where ever you're calling SetActive(), it's happening during a world step, which isn't allowed.

What you should do is tag those bodies you wish to change the active state, and then do it after the world step. For example, put all the bodies in a list, then call SetActive() on each one in the list after the Step().

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Hmmm on second thought I probably ought to elaborate more on this. :)

The world->IsLocked assertion occurs whenever you perform something that changes the state of the world **while the world state is being updated**.

So you can't change the active state of a body any time during the world->Step method, which in 99.9% of all cases means you're trying to do this in one of the collision callback methods. The other 0.01% is due to an attempt to multithread the physics simulation.

Also, adding/destroying bodies can't be done during the collision callback methods either. You have to mark that body and change the state of the body after the world->Step() method ran.